# Magento 2 : Out-of-stock not selectable option

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, out-of-stock, select

I display out-of-Stock in my configurable products. But it is selectable, I like to set as not selectable option for only out of stock. Please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send product's stock status into jsConfig using plugin

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="vendor_configurable_product_configurable"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Configurable"
                sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Configurable.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;

class Configurable
{

    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;
    protected $stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {

        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    public function aroundGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $status = [];
        $config = $proceed();
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($config);

        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            $stockitem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem(
                $product->getId(),
                $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
            );
            $status[$product->getId()] = $stockitem->getIsInStock();
        }

        $config['status'] = $status;

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

Override `swatch-renderer.js` from

> vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

to

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

And change `_RenderSwatchOptions` function with below code

```
_RenderSwatchOptions: function (config, controlId) {
    var optionConfig = this.options.jsonSwatchConfig[config.id],
        optionClass = this.options.classes.optionClass,
        moreLimit = parseInt(this.options.numberToShow, 10),
        moreClass = this.options.classes.moreButton,
        moreText = this.options.moreButtonText,
        countAttributes = 0,
        html = '',
        $widget = this;//Added custom code

    if (!this.options.jsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(config.id)) {
        return '';
    }

    $.each(config.options, function () {
        var id,
            type,
            value,
            thumb,
            label,
            attr;

        if (!optionConfig.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
            return '';
        }

        // Add more button
        if (moreLimit === countAttributes++) {
            html += '<a href="#" class="' + moreClass + '">' + moreText + '</a>';
        }

        id = this.id;
        type = parseInt(optionConfig[id].type, 10);
        value = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('value') ? optionConfig[id].value : '';
        thumb = optionConfig[id].hasOwnProperty('thumb') ? optionConfig[id].thumb : '';
        label = this.label ? this.label : '';
        attr =
            ' id="' + controlId + '-item-' + id + '"' +
            ' aria-checked="false"' +
            ' aria-describedby="' + controlId + '"' +
            ' tabindex="0"' +
            ' option-type="' + type + '"' +
            ' option-id="' + id + '"' +
            ' option-label="' + label + '"' +
            ' aria-label="' + label + '"' +
            ' option-tooltip-thumb="' + thumb + '"' +
            ' option-tooltip-value="' + value + '"' +
            ' role="option"';

        if (!this.hasOwnProperty('products') || this.products.length <= 0) {
            attr += ' option-empty="true"';
        }

        /*Added custom code*/
        var disabledStyle = '';
        if(!$widget.options.jsonConfig.status[this.products[0]]){
            disabledStyle = 'pointer-events: none; cursor:not-allowed;';
        }

        if (type === 0) {
            // Text
            html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' text" ' + attr + '>' + (value ? value : label) +
                '</div>';
        } else if (type === 1) {
            // Color
            html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' color" ' + attr +
                ' style="background: ' + value +
                ' no-repeat center; background-size: initial;'+disabledStyle+'" >' + '' +
                '</div>';//Added custom code
        } else if (type === 2) {
            // Image
            html += '<div class="' + optionClass + ' image" ' + attr +
                ' style="background: url(' + value + ') no-repeat center; background-size: initial;">' + '' +
                '</div>';
        } else if (type === 3) {
            // Clear
            html += '<div class="' + optionClass + '" ' + attr + '></div>';
        } else {
            // Default
            html += '<div class="' + optionClass + '" ' + attr + '>' + label + '</div>';
        }
    });

    return html;
},
```

This will only works for text swatches and color swatches.